# how to install packages from the file?

Tags: python, django, django-cms, pythonanywhere

please help to solve the problem.

on the hosting pythonanywhere.com I chose a project with python2.7 and try to install packages from the file requirments.txt. use the command:

```
pip2.7 install --user -r requirments.txt
```

The result is the following error message:

```
Downloading/unpacking djangocms-picture==0.1 (from -r requirments.txt (line 19))
  Downloading djangocms_picture-0.1-py2-none-any.whl (154kB): 154kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking djangocms-style==1.4 (from -r requirments.txt (line 20))
  Downloading djangocms_style-1.4-py27-none-any.whl (111kB): 111kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking djangocms-teaser==0.1 (from -r requirments.txt (line 21))
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send
    raise ProxyError(e)
ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))

Storing debug log for failure in /home/blogik5/.pip/pip.log
09:41 ~/blogik5 $
```

requirments.txt:

```
Django==1.6.8
Pillow==2.6.1
South==1.0.1
argparse==1.2.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-classy-tags==0.5.1
django-cms==3.0.6
django-mptt==0.6.1
django-reversion==1.8.4
django-sekizai==0.7
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.2
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-file==0.1
djangocms-flash==0.1
djangocms-googlemap==0.2
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.5.4
djangocms-link==1.5
djangocms-picture==0.1
djangocms-style==1.4
djangocms-teaser==0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.4.1
djangocms-video==0.1
html5lib==0.999
pytz==2014.7
six==1.8.0
sorl-thumbnail==11.12
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

on mail I received a letter:

```
 You've used up your daily CPU allowance of 100 seconds on PythonAnywhere today, so your processes have been put in a tarpit. This means that they will continue to run, but at a reduced priority. There's more about the PythonAnywhere tarpit here.

You can get more CPU resources by upgrading your PythonAnywhere plan from the accounts page.
```

please tell me where I go wrong?

Comment: Can't you leave off the "2.7"? `pip install...`

Comment: I've tried. the result is the same

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- that looks like an error with our proxy (all external Internet access for free accounts goes through it), but I'm not aware of any problems with the proxy yesterday.  Could you try again now?